# MVC custom authorize attribute

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authorization, authorize-attribute

We use Windows Authentication on our web apps at work here.

I have extended MVC's `AuthorizeAttribute`, so that it reads authorized users and roles from the web.config file. I override `AuthorizeCore()` to make sure the current user is one from the config file.

My co-worker and I have a bit of a debate here. He feels that it makes it too easy for a malicious individual to add himself to the web.config if he gains access to the server, he believes the standard access attribute with the users and roles hard coded should be used, thus someone would have to recompile to give themselves access... or have a hex editor.

Curious if my method of putting authorized roles in the web.config is considered poor practice? What is the collective opinion of the SO community.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Storing sensitive information in the web.config is generally accepted as a reasonable practice. The file is not served up by IIS, and generally if some one with malicious intent manages to compromise your site to the point where they CAN read your web.config, you typically have much larger security concern than just being able to manipulate that one file. If being able to read the web.config is a concern you still have, you could always encrypt it's contents. I haven't done this personally but my understanding is that it's pretty easy to do.

Comment: I figured this question may turn into a holy war, but I am glad there is atleast one answer... and it agrees with me. :)